# Generating RSS feed under Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rss

I want to provide rss feed under google app engine/python.

I've tried to use usual request handler and generate xml response. When I access the feed url directly, I can see the feed correctly, however, when I'm trying to subscribe to the feed in google reader, it says that

> 'The feed being requested cannot be found.'

I wonder whether this approach is right. I was considering using a static xml file and updating it by cron jobs. But while GAE doesn't support file i/o, this approach seems not going to work.

How to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: my guess would be you need to probably set the correct content type in the response headers in order for the browser to recognize it as an rss feed. but I'm too lazy at the moment to look up what the content type is to give you a formal answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There're 2 solutions I suggest:

1. [GAE-REST](https://github.com/fczuardi/gae-rest) you can just add to your project and configure and it will make RSS for you but the project is old and no longer maintained.
2. Do like I do, use a template to write a list to and like this I could succeed generating RSS (GeoRSS) that can be read via google reader where template is:

   ```
   <title>{{host}}</title>
   <link href="http://{{host}}" rel="self"/>
   <id>http://{{host}}/</id>
   <updated>2011-09-17T08:14:49.875423Z</updated>
   <generator uri="http://{{host}}/">{{host}}</generator>

   {% for entity in entities %}

   <entry>

   <title><![CDATA[{{entity.title}}]]></title>
   <link href="http://{{host}}/vi/{{entity.key.id}}"/>
   <id>http://{{host}}/vi/{{entity.key.id}}</id>
   <updated>{{entity.modified.isoformat}}Z</updated>
   <author><name>{{entity.title|escape}}</name></author>
   <georss:point>{{entity.geopt.lon|floatformat:2}},{{entity.geopt.lat|floatformat:2}}</georss:point>
   <published>{{entity.added}}</published>
   <summary type="xhtml"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">{{entity.text|escape}}</div>
   </summary>

   </entry>

   {% endfor %}

   </feed>
   ```

My handler is (you can also do this with python 2.7 as just a function outside a handler for a more minimal solution):

```
class GeoRSS(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        start = datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=60)
        count = (int(self.request.get('count'
                 )) if not self.request.get('count') == '' else 1000)
        try:
            entities = memcache.get('entities')
        except KeyError:
            entity = Entity.all().filter('modified >',
                                  start).filter('published =',
                    True).order('-modified').fetch(count)
        memcache.set('entities', entities)
        template_values = {'entities': entities, 'request': self.request,
                           'host': os.environ.get('HTTP_HOST',
                           os.environ['SERVER_NAME'])}
        dispatch = 'templates/georss.html'
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), dispatch)
        output = template.render(path, template_values)
        self.response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public,max-age=%s' \
            % 86400
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/rss+xml'
        self.response.out.write(output)
```

I hope some of this works for you, both ways worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have an Atom feed generator for my blog, which runs on AppEngine/Python. I use the Django 1.2 template engine to construct the feed. My template looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
      xml:lang="en"
      xml:base="http://www.example.org">
  <id>urn:uuid:4FC292A4-C69C-4126-A9E5-4C65B6566E05</id>
  <title>Adam Crossland's Blog</title>
  <subtitle>opinions and rants on software and...things</subtitle>
  <updated>{{ updated }}</updated>
  <author>
    <name>Adam Crossland</name>
    <email>adam@adamcrossland.net</email>
  </author>
  <link href="http://blog.adamcrossland.net/" />
  <link rel="self" href="http://blog.adamcrossland.net/home/feed" />
  {% for each_post in posts %}{{ each_post.to_atom|safe }}
  {% endfor %}
</feed>
```

**Note: if you use any of this, you'll need to create your own uuid to go into the *id* node.**

The updated node should contain the time and date on which contents of the feed were last updated in [rfc 3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) format. Fortunately, Python has a library to take care of this for you. An excerpt from the controller that generates the feed:

```
    from rfc3339 import rfc3339

    posts = Post.get_all_posts()
    self.context['posts'] = posts

    # Initially, we'll assume that there are no posts in the blog and provide
    # an empty date.
    self.context['updated'] = ""

    if posts is not None and len(posts) > 0:
        # But there are posts, so we will pick the most recent one to get a good
        # value for updated.
        self.context['updated'] = rfc3339(posts[0].updated(), utc=True)

    response.content_type = "application/atom+xml"
```

Don't worry about the `self.context['updated']` stuff. That just how my framework provides a shortcut for setting template variables. The import part is that I encode the date that I want to use with the `rfc3339` function. Also, I set the `content_type` property of the Response object to be `application/atom+xml`.

The only other missing piece is that the template uses a method called `to_atom` to turn the `Post` object into Atom-formatted data:

```
def to_atom(self):
    "Create an ATOM entry block to represent this Post."

    from rfc3339 import rfc3339

    url_for = self.url_for()
    atom_out = "<entry>\n\t<title>%s</title>\n\t<link href=\"http://blog.adamcrossland.net/%s\" />\n\t<id>%s</id>\n\t<summary>%s</summary>\n\t<updated>%s</updated>\n  </entry>" % (self.title, url_for, self.slug_text, self.summary_for(), rfc3339(self.updated(), utc=True))

    return atom_out
```

That's all that is required as far as I know, and this code does generate a perfectly-nice and working feed for my blog. Now, if you really want to do RSS instead of Atom, you'll need to change the format of the feed template, the Post template and the content_type, but I think that is the essence of what you need to do to get a feed generated from an AppEngine/Python application.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing special about generating XML as opposed to HTML - provided you set the content type correctly. Pass your feed to the validator at http://validator.w3.org/feed/ and it will tell you what's wrong with it.

If that doesn't help, you'll need to show us your source - we can't debug your code for you if you won't show it to us.